# Handling requests for deprecated RSS feeds

Tags: redirects, rss, best-practices

The site I run still gets pinged frequently by RSS readers and services, even though we deprecated support for those feeds over two years ago. The URLs currently return a 404.

Are there any good conventions for letting clients know that the feed is gone for good and that they should stop hitting us?

I'm considering redirecting to a single-entry RSS feed with a post explaining that our organization no longer supports RSS. Good idea? Bad idea?

Comment: Just a guess, but I could imagine that there are feed readers out there which don’t follow redirects. -- Instead of a `404`, `410` would make more sense; however, again, probably there are feed readers that don’t differentiate between them. -- Would it be possible for you to serve a single-entry feed on the old URL? That way you could at least make sure that the users receive the entry.